# Iterate bamboo Repositories via ssh task

Tags: ssh, bamboo

I have a plan in bamboo, with n Repos. Via ssh task i would like to iterate through each of them. The total number of Repos is dynamic.

Bamboo variables explained here

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html

My approaches look like this:

```
touch test.txt

#get count
echo "count ${bamboo.planRepository[@]}\n" >> test.text

for repo in "${bamboo.planRepository[@]}"
do
 echo "${repo.name}\n" > test.txt

done


START=1
END=5
i=$START
while [[ $i -le $END ]]
do
    printf "${bamboo.planRepository.${i}.name}\n" > test.txt
    ((i = i + 1))
done
```

Im not firm with ssh script syntax and nothing did work.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: What do you see in Bamboo build log? Also, does this script run from command prompt after you substitute with the appropriate variables?

Comment: thx. using bamboo specs now. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-specs-894743906.html